# Is it necessary to normalize the dependent variable if independent variable is normalized by firm size?

Tags: normalization

I am working with firm-level panel dataset spanning multiple industries. I normalized the independent variables (e.g. inventory) *by firm size* (measured using firm assets) in order *to control for firm size*. My dependent variables (DV) are Sales and Profit. Do I need to normalize DVs as well just because I normalized my independent variables? I notice that my results change depending on whether I use a normalized DV vs. not-normalized.